I use springboot websocket stomp rabbitmq meet ERROR message:Connection to broker closed
Affects: <Spring Framework version> 5.1.13  ,rabbitmq 3.7.5
Waiting for an indefinite minute, encountering such a mistake a\["ERROR\\nmessage:Connection to broker closed.\\ncontent-length:0\\n\\n\\u0000"\] come from webpage.
backend log:
2024-05-22 09:43:15.624 DEBUG \[tcp-client-loop-nio-6\] r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\] Channel cleaned, now 1 active connections and 1 inactive connections
2024-05-22 09:43:15.624 DEBUG \[tcp-client-loop-nio-6\] r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\] Channel closed, now 1 active connections and 0 inactive connections
2024-05-22 09:43:15.624 DEBUG \[tcp-client-loop-nio-6\] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\] Non Removed handler: StompMessageDecoder, context: ChannelHandlerContext(StompMessageDecoder, \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.onChannelReadIdle = reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InboundIdleStateHandler), (StompMessageDecoder = org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.ReactorNettyTcpClient$StompMessageDecoder), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2024-05-22 09:43:15.624 DEBUG \[tcp-client-loop-nio-6\] reactor.netty.ReactorNetty - \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\] Non Removed handler: reactor.left.onChannelReadIdle, context: ChannelHandlerContext(reactor.left.onChannelReadIdle, \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\]), pipeline: DefaultChannelPipeline{(reactor.left.onChannelReadIdle = reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$InboundIdleStateHandler), (StompMessageDecoder = org.springframework.messaging.tcp.reactor.ReactorNettyTcpClient$StompMessageDecoder), (reactor.right.reactiveBridge = reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler)}
2024-05-22 09:43:15.625 DEBUG \[tcp-client-loop-nio-6\] r.n.r.PooledConnectionProvider - \[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\] onStateChange(ChannelOperations{PooledConnection{channel=\[id: 0xad634737, L:/10.1.201.30:54553 ! R:/192.168.175.12:61613\]}}, \[disconnecting\])
2024-05-22 09:43:15.625 DEBUG \[tcp-client-scheduler-6\] o.s.m.s.s.StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler - TCP connection to broker closed in session mpw022x1

public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic", "/queue", "/temp-queue/", "/amq/queue", "/exchange")
.setAutoStartup(true)
.setRelayHost(stompCfg.getRelayHost())
.setRelayPort(stompCfg.getRelayPort())
.setVirtualHost(stompCfg.getVirtualHost())
.setClientLogin(stompCfg.getClientLogin())
.setClientPasscode(stompCfg.getClientPasscode())
.setSystemLogin(stompCfg.getSystemLogin())
.setSystemPasscode(stompCfg.getSystemPasscode()).setSystemHeartbeatSendInterval(60000L).setSystemHeartbeatReceiveInterval(60000L)
.setUserDestinationBroadcast("/topic/unresolved-user-destination")
.setUserRegistryBroadcast("/topic/simp-user-registry")
.setTcpClient(initTcpClient(stompCfg.getRelayHost(),stompCfg.getRelayPort()));

              //  initTcpClient(stompCfg.getRelayHost(),stompCfg.getRelayPort()));
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    
    }
    
    private ReactorNettyTcpClient<byte[]> initTcpClient(String relayHost,int relayPort ) {
        StompDecoder decoder = new StompDecoder();
        ReactorNettyCodec<byte[]> codec = new StompReactorNettyCodec(decoder);
        ReactorNettyTcpClient<byte[]> client = new ReactorNettyTcpClient<>(tcpClient -> tcpClient
                .host(relayHost)
                .port(relayPort)
        , codec);
        client.setLogger(SimpLogging.forLog(client.getLogger()));
        return client;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        //HeartbeatTime
        registry.addEndpoint("/qa-ws").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS().setHeartbeatTime(20000L)
               .setWebSocketEnabled(true);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void configureWebSocketTransport(WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
        registration.setSendTimeLimit(10 * 1000).setSendBufferSizeLimit(512 * 1024);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8192);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8192);
        //最大空闲时间60秒
        container.setMaxSessionIdleTimeout(60000L);
    
        return container;
    }


Is there any mistake? Looking forward to your reply.
how fix it.
here I add ，No close will occur. Experienced experts, can you tell me if this is okay?
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/5.1.x/spring-messaging/src/main/java/org/springframework/messaging/simp/stomp/StompBrokerRelayMessageHandler.java#L612
 @Override
 public void afterConnected(TcpConnection<byte[]> connection) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("TCP connection " + connection + " opened in session=" + getSessionId());
            }
            this.tcpConnection = connection;
            connection.onReadInactivity(() -> {
                if (this.tcpConnection != null && !this.isStompConnected) {
                    handleTcpConnectionFailure("No CONNECTED frame received in " +
                            MAX_TIME_TO_CONNECTED_FRAME + " ms.", null);
                }
            }, MAX_TIME_TO_CONNECTED_FRAME);
            connection.sendAsync(MessageBuilder.createMessage(EMPTY_PAYLOAD, this.connectHeaders.getMessageHeaders()));


                //here I add ，No close will occur. Experienced experts, can you tell me if this is okay?
   connection.onWriteInactivity(() ->
                        connection.send(HEARTBEAT_MESSAGE).addCallback(
                                result -> {},
                                ex -> handleTcpConnectionFailure(
                                        "Failed to forward heartbeat: " + ex.getMessage(), ex)), interval);

 
        }

